# Angular UI-Router: Can't access state name from service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to detect the name of the current state from a service.

Problem: `$state.current.name` returns null.

```
app.factory('rootUserService', ['$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$rootScope', '$q', 'socketFactory', function($http, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, $q, socketFactory) {
 return {

  guestOrNot: function(res) {
    if ( res._id === 'someid' ) { 
      $rootScope.isGuest = true;
    } 
    else {
      $rootScope.isGuest = false;

      // if current state = app.landing, do something. 

      console.log($state) // current.name field is 'app.landing'
      console.log($state.current) // name field is empty
      console.log($state.includes('app.landing')) // returns false no matter what.
    };
  }

}]);
```

console.log($state) returns below:
[image]

console.log($state.current) returns below
[image]

Comment: More info please! If `console.log($state)` has the info you need, but the line right after doesn't - then there is an error in how you're trying to access those properties. What is the actual output of those `log` calls?

Comment: There are no errors between the two console logs.